# Feature selection + cross-validation, but how to make ROC-curves in R

Tags: r, feature-selection, cross-validation, roc

I'm stuck with the next problem. I divide my data into 10 folds. Each time, I use 1 fold as test set and the other 9 as training set (I do this ten times). On each training set, I do feature selection (filter methode with chi.squared) and then I make a SVMmodel with my training set and the selected features.
So at the end, I become 10 different models (because of the feature selection). But now I want to make a ROC-curve in R from this filter methode in general. How can I do this?

Silke

Comment: there are serveral tutorials: http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/ http://www.r-bloggers.com/roc-curves-and-classification/

Comment: Or do you have a general problem with ROC curves?

Comment: No, but I want to make from this 10 different models only 1 ROC-curve that represents the performance from this feature selection method

Comment: From what I understand it only makes sense to have a curve for each model, but you can put them into one plot if you like.

Comment: So it is not possible to make 1 curve from this cross-validation? And has it sense to take the average from their areas under the curve?

Comment: I'm not sure about making 1 curve from 10 models, I've never done that before. But yes, you can compute the average AUC. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: maybe you can include some more information on your data and code.

Comment: I've got in my project several different methods of feature selection. And now I want a method to compare them. So I think about ROC-curves. So I search for every method the performance of that method

Comment: I see. so yes, averaging the AUC makes sense. You still should check whether the difference is significant. I'd suggest you perform a t test. You can also compute the accuracy for each 'fold' and average over the ten folds per feature selection method and perform a t test on the accuracies. Comparing the accuracies is what I have in the past, but comparing the AUC can also be useful.

Comment: you need to post code on your cross-validation method before anyone can help you with averaging your prediction models.

Comment: she didn't ask for help about how to average. just if it makes sense.

Comment: I've found a good method. By my cross-validation I get a vector of predictions (10 little vectors become one) en this vector I can use for making my roc-curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed store the predictions *if they are all on the same scale* (be especially careful about this as you perform feature selection... some methods may produce scores that are dependent on the number of features) and use them to build a ROC curve. Here is the code I used for [a recent paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212963413000065):

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
k <- 10
n <- dim(aSAH)[1]
indices <- sample(rep(1:k, ceiling(n/k))[1:n])

all.response <- all.predictor <- aucs <- c()
for (i in 1:k) {
  test = aSAH[indices==i,]
  learn = aSAH[indices!=i,]
  model <- glm(as.numeric(outcome)-1 ~ s100b + ndka + as.numeric(wfns), data = learn, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
  model.pred <- predict(model, newdata=test)
  aucs <- c(aucs, roc(test$outcome, model.pred)$auc)
  all.response <- c(all.response, test$outcome)
  all.predictor <- c(all.predictor, model.pred)
}

roc(all.response, all.predictor)
mean(aucs)
```

The roc curve is built from `all.response` and `all.predictor` that are updated at each step. This code also stores the AUC at each step in `auc` for comparison. Both results should be quite similar when the sample size is sufficiently large, however small samples within the cross-validation may lead to underestimated AUC as the ROC curve with all data will tend to be smoother and less underestimated by the trapezoidal rule.