# Is my ROC curve different from null hypothesis?

Tags: r, roc, auc

I have drawn a ROC curve with `pROC` package :

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
ROCA <- plot.roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100, percent=TRUE, col="BLUE")
ROCB <- lines.roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$ndka, percent=TRUE, col="RED")
legend("bottomright", legend=c("A", "B"), col=c("BLUE", "RED"), lwd=2)
```

**I want to test if curve A is different from null hypothesis (grey line)** but the only test I can find is comparing curve A and B.

```
comparecurves <- roc.test(ROCA, ROCB)
text(20, 40, labels=paste("p-value =", format.pval(comparecurves$p.value)))
```

This is what I get at the end:
[image: ROC]

I have read this : [ROC curve plot: 0.50 significant and cross-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932512/roc-curve-plot-0-50-significant-and-cross-validation) but it does not help me...
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the full area under the ROC curve, [the difference to the null hypothesis is equivalent to the Mann-Whitney U statistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206911/relationship-between-auc-and-u-mann-whitney-statistic). In R you can easily get it with the [`wilcox.test`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html) function, for instance:

```
wilcox.test(s100b ~ outcome, data = aSAH)
```

Comment: ok, so simply I just have to do : ```wilcox.test(s100b ~ outcome, data=aSAH)``` and that's it ?

Comment: @B_slash_ yes correct, I edited my answer to reflect that.